# How can I create third party cookies to track users data?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, third-party-cookies

i am building a react app where I will give users a cookie and they add it to their websites head and after that I can get users information.I want to get other websites users data and want to store it in database. I think third party cookies can help me with that.But I don't know what to do. If anybody has any solutions I will be grateful.

I tried first party cookies. Butit only stores my websites data.But I want to get other websites data by using the tracking cookies or third party cookies.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.